# Image Checkbox in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on a form for the iphone and I would like a female/male button choice. The buttons originally have an M and an F written on them and when you choose one, an image flips over. I managed to display the images when the buttons are pressed. The problem I was having is that they were able to both be displayed at the same time but when one is enabled the other image should disappear. I've tried to correct it and now the program crashes. 
 implementation file:

```
-(IBAction) setCheckBox2: (id) sender
{
    UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"female.tiff"];
    // UIImage *notSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"male.tiff"];

    if (sender == selected)

    {
        [sender setImage:selected];
    }
    else
    {

        [sender setImage:NO];  
    }
```

Then I was going to create another function for the male image being selected. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to use UISegmentedBar.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing that `sender == selected` hence implying that `sender` is of type `UIImage`, and then sending `setImage:` to `sender`... with itself as parameter.

This doen't make sense. I think what you were trying to do must look something like:

```
-(IBAction) setCheckBox2: (UIImageView *) sender
{
    UIImage *selected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"female.tiff"];
    UIImage *notSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"male.tiff"];

    if (sender.image == selected)

    {
        [sender setImage:notSelected];
    }
    else
    {

        [sender setImage:selected];  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not you are using `default`(for not selected) and `selected`(for selected) property for these two state. The advantage to do this is you will not have to write a bunch of code. OK set selected image and default image.

> Take a `global` variable of `UIButton` for `currentSelectedButton`.
>   connect both the `UIButton` with single `IBActionMethod` named `genderButtonClicked`(or you want).
>   Now

```
-(IBAction)genderButtonClicked:(UIButton)sender
{
    if(currentSelectedButton)
        [currentSelectedButton setSelected:FALSE];
    currentSelectedButton = sender;
    [currentSelectedButton setSelected:TRUE];
}
```

I Think this will solve your problem